# How to replace both int and string

Tags: java

I have a String like "HelloWorld!9090Hello" in a file, and i want to replace the whole string with a new One, Tried this but didn't helped

Example File abc.txt:

> a=HelloWorld!9090Hello

```
String neww = "abcdef";
File file = new File("abc.txt");
File wr = new File("tmp.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
// tried even line.toString();//    
String rline= line.replace("HelloWorld!9090Hello", neww);
BufferWrite(rline,wr);

}
br.close();
public static void BufferWrite(String St,File file) throws IOException{

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(St);
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.close();

    }
```

The BufferWrite() writes text to the tmp.txt file..

Result :

> a=HelloWorld!9090Hello

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: *"How to replace both text and string"* What's the difference between "text" and "string"? Aren't all text strings? Aren't all strings text?

Comment: *"and neww is a String Variable"* Yes we can see that from reading your code.  You need to tell us things that *aren't* obvious from reading your code, such as: in detail what you're trying to accomplish, your expected results, your actual results, any errors you might be getting, etc.

Comment: I am getting no errors. It runs but doesn't Replaces

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code that you've shown us, so I can only assume that your error is in the code that you haven't (e.g. your `BufferWrite` method).

Comment: Is it possible that BufferWrite is opening the file every time it is called, then writes the current line, and then closes it, rather than appending lines to the existing file?  Maybe your source file has a blank line at the end, and that is tromping your file.

Comment: check the BufferWrite now

Comment: Doesn't String.replace(String, String) expect the first parameter to be a regular expression and not the value to find specifically?

Answer (score -1):

I ran your exact code in Eclipse, and it creates the tmp file correctly for me and it has "abcdef" in it.

Did you make sure you actually started with exactly "HelloWorld!9090Hello" in your input file? It looks like you are starting with "a=HelloWorld!9090Hello", not "HelloWorld!9090Hello". The replace function will only work when the Strings are an exact match. If you're starting with "a=HelloWorld!9090Hello", change the replace function to the following:

```
String rline= line.replace("a=HelloWorld!9090Hello", neww);
```

Comment: String replace replaces whatever character you tell it to find with what you provide it, so what he should be expecting to see in his example is "a=abcdef". See an example here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm

Comment: String.replace only replaces text in a file,, what i wanna do is to change both int and text...

Comment: Thanks for your link Brandon. Yes, you're right. Well the exact code still works locally for me, so it must be something with the OP's environment or input file. It doesn't seem like a code issue.